# Missing packages and repos setting up webmin on VPS

Tags: debian, vps, webmin

I'm just trying to set up webmin as the first thing on a new VPS, I'm familiar with Ubuntu (it's my main work machine).

This is what's on the VPS

```
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.5 (jessie)
Release:    8.5
Codename:    jessie
```

So I follow the instructions to download and install virtualmin:

```
wget http://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/scripts/install.sh
sudo /bin/sh install.sh
```

It starts well but eventually fails:

[INFO] Started installation log in /root/virtualmin-install.log

```
▣□□ Phase 1 of 3: Setup
Installing extra dependencies for Debian 8                              [  ✔  ]
Downloading apt.gpg                                                     [  ✔  ]
Adding GPG key for PHP7 packages                                        [  ✔  ]
Downloading RPM-GPG-KEY-virtualmin-6                                    [  ✔  ]
Downloading RPM-GPG-KEY-webmin                                          [  ✔  ]
Installing Virtualmin 6 key                                             [  ✔  ]
Installing Webmin key                                                   [  ✔  ]
Updating apt metadata                                                   [  ✔  ]
Downloading repository metadata                                         [  ✔  ]
Disabling cdrom: repositories                                           [  ✔  ]
Cleaning out old metadata                                               [  ✔  ]

▣▣□ Phase 2 of 3: Installation
Installing Webmin                                                       [ERROR] Failed with error: 100
[  ✘  ]

[ERROR] Something went wrong. Exiting.
[ERROR] The last few log entries were:
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 webmin : Depends: libauthen-pam-perl but it is not installable
          Depends: libio-pty-perl but it is not installable
          Depends: apt-show-versions but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

#

Here's what sources.list looks like

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
#deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
#deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
deb http://software.virtualmin.com/vm/6/gpl/apt virtualmin-jessie main
deb http://software.virtualmin.com/vm/6/gpl/apt virtualmin-universal main
```

So then I try to install a missing package (and get the same rsponse for every missing package):

```
sudo apt install libauthen-pam-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libauthen-pam-perl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libauthen-pam-perl' has no installation candidate
```

So, I try to add the repo that contains `apt-show-versions` (one of the missing packages):

sudo add-apt-repository ...

But that command (add-apt-repository) doesn't exist. So I try to load `software-properties-common` and that package cannot be located either.

How do I get out of this insanity and just get something loaded?

This is what I get for `sudo apt update`:

```
Hit http://software.virtualmin.com virtualmin-jessie InRelease                                                   
Hit http://software.virtualmin.com virtualmin-universal InRelease                                                
Hit http://packages.sury.org jessie InRelease                                                                    
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease                 
Hit http://software.virtualmin.com virtualmin-jessie/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://packages.sury.org jessie/main amd64 Packages                                    
Get:1 http://packages.sury.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB [169 B]                       
Get:2 http://packages.sury.org jessie/main Translation-en [169 B]                         
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources                         
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Sources                                      
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages                                  
Get:3 http://packages.sury.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB [169 B]                               
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib amd64 Packages                                                    
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en                                   
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en                                      
Get:4 http://packages.sury.org jessie/main Translation-en [169 B]                
Hit http://software.virtualmin.com virtualmin-universal/main amd64 Packages                         
Get:5 http://packages.sury.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB [169 B]
Get:6 http://packages.sury.org jessie/main Translation-en [169 B]                  
Get:7 http://packages.sury.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB [169 B]
Get:8 http://packages.sury.org jessie/main Translation-en [169 B]                  
Get:9 http://packages.sury.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB [169 B]            
Ign http://packages.sury.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB                             
Get:10 http://packages.sury.org jessie/main Translation-en [169 B]
Ign http://packages.sury.org jessie/main Translation-en        
Ign http://software.virtualmin.com virtualmin-jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://software.virtualmin.com virtualmin-jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://software.virtualmin.com virtualmin-universal/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://software.virtualmin.com virtualmin-universal/main Translation-en
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib
```

Then `sudo apt update` and execute your script.

The package [`libauthen-pam-perl`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libauthen-pam-perl/download) (and the missing dependencies) will be installed automatically from the `main` repository while executing the install script.

Answer (score 0):

Failed to install Webmin on Ubuntu 20.04.

To fix complaints about missing installation candidate

```
E: Package 'libauthen-pam-perl' has no installation candidate
```

run

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

then

```
sudo apt install webmin
```